# Flutter Webview Url management

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

Hello everyone I have a app created with `webview_flutter: ^2.0.2` this plugin I want to manage the url like a browser does. Like I want to show the user on which url currently they are. If the user click on any item on webview it reflect the url but not reload the page. I want to catch the url

> Note: I you need my code I can end it to you

Answer (score 1):

In [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) you get callback on

1. [PageStartedCallback](https://pub.dev/documentation/webview_flutter/latest/webview_flutter/PageStartedCallback.html)
2. [PageLoadingCallback](https://pub.dev/documentation/webview_flutter/latest/webview_flutter/PageLoadingCallback.html)
3. [PageFinishedCallback](https://pub.dev/documentation/webview_flutter/latest/webview_flutter/PageFinishedCallback.html)

On [PageStartedCallback](https://pub.dev/documentation/webview_flutter/latest/webview_flutter/PageStartedCallback.html) callback you can get current url and assign it your variable like this.

```
WebView(
         onPageStarted(String url){
                  _appBarText = url;
                  setState((){});
           },
           ........
        ),
```

Comment: If the page is not reloaded but some webview content has clicked and url has been changed can i get that url?